# I want to specify code_sale from table salles where I have an array of values ​but it only returns according to the first value in the array

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $array1=['A1','A2','A3','A4'];
    $test=salle::select('code_salle','type_salle')->where('code_salle',$array1)->get();
     return $test;
```

return

```
[{"code_salle":"A1","type_salle":"AMPHI"}]
```

Maybe I'm wrong in the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to try `whereIn` instead:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

```
$array1=['A1','A2','A3','A4'];
$test=salle::select('code_salle','type_salle')->whereIn('code_salle',$array1)->get();
return $test;
```